# Remove commas from all columns except one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

```
df
               
   date           price      vol    
0 2010-01-04  34,57282657    2,600,000
1 2010-01-04  123,900        2,600,000
2 2010-01-04  353,6789738    2,600,000
```

Is there a way to remove commas from all columns except 1 or 2 (here, just date) in general code? (I have 20 columns in reality.)

Expected output:

```
   date           price      vol    
0 2010-01-04  3457282657    2600000
1 2010-01-04  123900        2600000
2 2010-01-04  3536789738    2600000
```

Comment: The answer depends on the data type, hence it's important to first understand what data types pandas as imposed on the different columns. Is the `,` denoting a comma separator, a thousand separator or is the data type a string?  In our example above it seems that in the price column, the `,` is denoting decimal separator but in the vol column its denoting a thousand separator. You can see what data types you have by invoking `df.info()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) on columns of dataframe excluding the columns from `exclude` list:

```
exclude = ['date']

c = df.columns.difference(exclude)
df[c] = df[c].replace(',', '', regex=True)
```

Result:

```
         date       price      vol
0  2010-01-04  3457282657  2600000
1  2010-01-04      123900  2600000
2  2010-01-04  3536789738  2600000
```

Comment: I think this is more Pythonic but I have but i find `filter` more useful since you can use patterns and `like`

Comment: @Manakin yep :)

Answer (score 1):

You could replace by specific column *positions* using `.iloc` with `.replace` and passing `regex=True`. For example, this is how it would look to replace everything after the first column with `df.iloc[:,1:]`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].replace(',','', regex=True)
df

Out[19]: 
         date       price      vol
0  2010-01-04  3457282657  2600000
1  2010-01-04      123900  2600000
2  2010-01-04  3536789738  2600000
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution imo is to use `thousands=','` in your read statement i.e

`pd.read_csv(...,thousands=',')`

```
from io import StringIO


d = """   date           price      vol    
0 2010-01-04  34,57282657    2,600,000
1 2010-01-04  123,900        2,600,000
2 2010-01-04  353,6789738    2,600,000"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep='\s+',thousands=',')

print(df)
         date       price      vol
0  2010-01-04  3457282657  2600000
1  2010-01-04      123900  2600000
2  2010-01-04  3536789738  2600000

print(df.dtypes)

date     object
price     int64
vol       int64
dtype: object
```

we can use `filter` and `replace`

hat tip to @Shubham Sharma for regex corrections.

```
df[df.filter(regex="^(?!date)").columns] = df.filter(regex="^(?!date)")\
                                                 .replace(",", "", regex=True)
```

`^(?!date)` excludes the date column - you can add more by using the bitwise OR symbol `|` `^(?!date|vol)`

```
print(df)

         date       price      vol
0  2010-01-04  3457282657  2600000
1  2010-01-04      123900  2600000
2  2010-01-04  3536789738  2600000
```

## Explanation

1. ^ asserts position at start of a line
2. Negative Lookahead (?!date|vol)

Comment: I think need to change regex pattern, because `[^date]` matches a single character not in the list.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thanks, my regex definitely needs practice.

Comment: No problem, i think  you mean `^(?!date|vol)`  ;).

Comment: Now its better :).

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you can convert the column into type int.

```
df.price.astype(int)
df.vol.astype(int)
```

Comment: this will rightly return a `ValueError` you need to deal with the strings first.